# Clob not printing properly in express application

Tags: node.js, express, oracle11g, node-oracledb

I have this table with a clob column. I connect to the database from my express app using the oracledb driver. I want to print out this clob. This is my code:

```
router.get('/:task_name', function (req,res) {
"use strict";

oracledb.getConnection(connAttrs.database, function (err, connection) {
    if (err) {
        // Error connecting to DB
        res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.status(500).send(JSON.stringify({
            status: 500,
            message: "Error connecting to DB",
            detailed_message: err.message
        }));
        return;
    }

    connection.execute("select solution from solvedtasks s join tasks t on t.TASK_ID = s.TASK_ID WHERE task_name= :task_name", [req.params.task_name],{
        outFormat: oracledb.OBJECT //resultSet:true,

    }, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            res.status(500).send(JSON.stringify({
                status: 500,
                message: "Error getting the user profile",
                detailed_message: err.message
            }));
        } else {
            res.contentType('application/json').status(200);
            res.send(JSON.stringify(result.rows[0]));
            console.log(result.rows[0]);
          //  fetchRowsFromRS(connection,res,result.resultSet,10);
        }
        // Release the connection

        connection.release(
            function (err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.error(err.message);
                } else {
                    console.log("GET /SolvedTasks : Connection released");
                }
            });

    });
  });
 });
```

Instead of printing the clob from my database I get something that looks like lob metadata. Has anyone else encountered this issue? Here is a screenshot of my output: 
[image: Clob output]

Answer (score 1):

So I solved this, I am posting an answer in case anyone has this problem. Apparently the original oracledb driver has some issues handling clobs. But there is a library that enhances its functionality, called simple-oracledb, very easy to use and install: https://github.com/sagiegurari/simple-oracledb

by using connection.query, clobs are properly handled:

```
 enter code here
connection.query('SELECT * FROM departments WHERE manager_id > :id', [110],      {
  splitResults: true, //True to enable to split the results into bulks, each bulk will invoke the provided callback (last callback invocation will have empty results)
  bulkRowsAmount: 100 //The amount of rows to fetch (for splitting results, that is the max rows that the callback will get for each callback invocation)
}, function onResults(error, results) {
  if (error) {
    //handle error...
  } else if (results.length) {
    //handle next bulk of results
  } else {
    //all rows read
  }
});
```